# Kubernetes nginx ingress 503 response

Tags: kubernetes, nginx-ingress

I'm still learning k8s, but I have a fairly simple set up, that as far as I can tell should be working fine.

I pulled the nginx-ingress:

```
kubectl apply -f https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes/ingress-nginx/controller-v1.1.0/deploy/static/provider/cloud/deploy.yaml
```

applied the ingress service:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$1
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/enable-cors: "true"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-origin: "*"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-methods: "PUT, GET, POST, OPTIONS, DELETE"
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/cors-allow-headers: "DNT,X-CustomHeader,X-LANG,Keep-Alive,User-Agent,X-Requested-With,If-Modified-Since,Cache-Control,Content-Type,X-Api-Key,X-Device-Id,Access-Control-Allow-Origin"
  
spec:
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - path: /?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: client-service
            port:
              number: 3000
      - path: /api/?(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
        backend:
          service:
            name: server-service
            port:
              number: 5000
  ingressClassName: nginx
```

and have a frontend service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 3000
      protocol: TCP
      targetPort: http-port
  selector:
    app: client
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: jowz/client:v4.2
          ports:
            - containerPort: 3000
              name: http-port
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
```

and backend service and deployment:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: server-service
spec:
  ports:
    - port: 5000
      protocol: TCP
  selector:
    app: server
  type: ClusterIP
```

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: server-deployment
spec:
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: server
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: server
          image: jowz/server:v1
          imagePullPolicy: Always
          ports:
            - containerPort: 5000
              name: nodejs-port
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: server
```

but getting a 503 response. Everything I've come across as far as debugging is that usually there is a typo or incorrect service name listed. I've checked all of that, I've gone and looked at 'describe' on every service in every namespace, looked at the pods listed in the Selectors, and all are running, no errors. To make for a more simplified readout, here is the output from
kubectl get pods --all-namespaces

```
NAMESPACE       NAME                                                 READY   STATUS      RESTARTS   AGE
ingress-nginx   client-deployment-9ccf8cf87-7g6qr                    1/1     Running     0          40h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-create-tsp4n                 0/1     Completed   0          44h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-admission-patch-q7spm                  0/1     Completed   1          44h
ingress-nginx   ingress-nginx-controller-86b55bb769-2bqs5            1/1     Running     0          44h
ingress-nginx   mongodb                                              1/1     Running     0          41h
ingress-nginx   server-deployment-df679664f-99nrq                    1/1     Running     0          41h
kube-system     event-exporter-gke-d4b7ff94-4st8l                    2/2     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     fluentbit-gke-xlv7v                                  2/2     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     gke-metrics-agent-fhnmq                              2/2     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     konnectivity-agent-697c66b96-bvfdw                   1/1     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     konnectivity-agent-autoscaler-864fff96c4-n9tlp       1/1     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     kube-dns-autoscaler-758c4689b9-7gzx8                 1/1     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     kube-dns-fc686db9b-hjl4d                             4/4     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     kube-proxy-gke-octodemo-default-pool-20afc590-94qj   1/1     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     l7-default-backend-9db4bd868-zgx8s                   1/1     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     metrics-server-6f6cdbf67d-m6hgv                      1/1     Running     0          40h
kube-system     metrics-server-v0.5.2-66bbcdbffc-bmzp6               2/2     Running     0          2d17h
kube-system     pdcsi-node-st68b                                     2/2     Running     0          40h
```

I have this cluster hosted on GKE, no errors listed in the console or logs either. I'm lost as to how else I can debug this.

Comment: If you're going to vote the post down, then at least put a comment as for the reason. Not helpful in anyway if you're not going to point out what you think is wrong with the post.

Answer (score 0):

Check if the services are working:

- You can use the `kubectl get services` command to check the status of the services and make sure they have IP addresses and ClusterIP type.
- Check the endpoint list: `kubectl get endpoints service-name`
- Check application availability: Proxy your service port and try to access it directly `kubectl port-forward <resource_type>/<resource_name> <local_port>:<remote_port>`